# if文のgcd==1のところがeを適切な値で入力しても真になりません

Tags: c

RSA暗号の暗号化のプログラムを作っている途中なのですが、if文の `gcd==1` のところがeを適切な値で入力しても真になりません。fとeの最大公約数を1にしたいプログラムです

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int gcd(int f,int e){

  int r;

  while(r!=0){
    r=f%e;
    f=e;
    e=r;
  }

  return f;

}

int main(void){

int hirabun;
int p;
int q;
int flag=0;
int i;
int n;
int e;
int f;
int r;

printf("平文となる数字を入力してください:");
scanf("%d",&hirabun);
printf("pを入力してください:");
scanf("%d",&p);
printf("qを入力してください:");
scanf("%d",&q);
for( i=2;i<p;++i ) {
   if( p%i==0 ) {
     flag = 1;
     break;
   }
 }

 if( flag==0 )
   printf("%d は素数です。\n",p);
 else
   printf("%d は素数ではありません。\n",p);

// return 0;

 for( i=2;i<q;++i ) {
    if( q%i==0 ) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  if( flag==0 )
    printf("%d は素数です。\n",q);
  else
    printf("%d は素数ではありません。\n",q);



  n=p*q;
  f=(p-1)*(q-1);



  printf("gcd(f,e)=1となるeを入力してください:");
  scanf ("%d",&e);
  if(gcd(f,e)==1)
   printf("gcd(f,e)=1です\n");
  else
   printf("違います");
   return 0;

  printf("eの値は%dです",e);
  printf("%d",gcd(f,e));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`gcd()`の`r`が未初期化であることが原因ですね。
`r`を0以外の値で初期化しないと`while(r!=0)`の処理が実行されません。

問題のコードをq.cに書いてコンパイルしたところ(clang -Wall q.c)、警告が出ていました。

警告を含め、クリーンコンパイルを心掛けることをお勧めします。

【コンパイル結果】

```
q.c:6:7: warning: variable 'r' is used uninitialized whenever function 'gcd' is called [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
  int r;
  ~~~~^
q.c:8:9: note: uninitialized use occurs here
  while(r!=0){
        ^
q.c:6:8: note: initialize the variable 'r' to silence this warning
  int r;
       ^
        = 0
q.c:28:5: warning: unused variable 'r' [-Wunused-variable]
int r;
    ^
2 warnings generated.
```